# How can I print the names of the files being processed in a Perl one-liner?

Tags: perl, command-line

I generally use perl one liners instead of grep to search through files.

For example following prints all the locations containing *`#include <stdio.h>`*

```
perl -ne "print if(/#include\s*[\"<]stdio.h/)" */*.[ch]
```

But I could not find a way to print the filename that got these lines. I tried to print `$ARGV[0]` but no avail.

So, how do you print the filenames that contain these lines?

Comment: Use grep. And then your problem will vanish (grep -l)

Comment: @depesz It only vanishes until you need to do something more complex.

Comment: Retracting my answer: $_ was being interpreted by the shell, not by perl, despite quotes etc. Try echo $_: The var contains the second part of the last command, which is why my answer appeared to be printing the filenames as required.

Comment: depesz, I don't have grep on my windows machine. But i do have perl;

Answer (score 10):

The variable that contains the name of the file that `*ARGV` is opened to is `$ARGV`, not `$ARGV[0]` (which is the first element of `@ARGV`).

```
print "$ARGV: $_" if /include\s*[\"<]stdio.h/;
```

Answer (score 4):

`$ARGV` is the special variable for the name of the file currently being read. I believe that is what you need.

Answer (score 4):

using [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/), that is a nice replacement (written in perl) for grep:

```
$ ack --cc '#include'
```

NB

I know, I'm cheating :-P

Comment: Indeed, ack is a great grep replacement.

Comment: Not cheating, but sed is the proper tool to replace grep.

Comment: @William: huh? `sed` edits, `grep` matches. How is `sed` the proper tool to replace `grep`?